# What is it needed to repair the pressure pads of an electric piano keyboard?

Tags: circuit-design, keyboard, motherboard, keypad

I don’t know if this is the right place to ask, but this is important to me, so i hope you understand. I have an electric piano keyboard (Korg Kross I). It is supposed to detect automatically the pressure (force) i give to the keyboard with my fingertips, and make a louder or quieter sound, proportionally. This mechanism is very important, and it’s been failing lately. I googled some info, and saw how to repair it in a video… but it says i need some sort of “*graffite*”? What kind of graffite is this? Can i get it on a regular electric components store? If this is not how it is repaired, what do i need to repair it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions about repair of consumer electronic devices usually get closed as being off-topic in this forum.

The word you're looking for is "graphite" (a powdered form of carbon), and you could find it as "conductive paint" but I would strongly recommend against taking your keyboard apart and painting that stuff on contacts.

If you have failing contacts in a synth keyboard, you should first clean it internally -- a meticulous job that requires careful disassembly and keeping all those keys and hammers sorted out. Dirt causes more failures than conductive pads wearing away.

Although you stated it detects pressure, the hammer-action keyboards I've seen actually detect velocity by measuring the time between actuation of two contacts for each key. That's more reliable than detecting a varying resistance caused by pressure.

If possible, get a service manual and study it first. Make sure you are capable of the work. Take YouTube videos with a grain of salt.

Comment: You can also find graphite in the form of pencil lead. Rubbing a pencil on one of those contacts can be reasonably effective at making it work again, though not amazing.

Comment: Ok! Thanks. I’ll try to search for the manual. Also, sorry for the consumer post, but didn’t know were else to look for reliable info.